# String hashing with quadratic probing, in Python

Tags: python, hashtable, quadratic-probing

I am trying to write a function in Python, that will add strings to a hash table and resolve any collisions with quadratic probing, without importing math.

```
def addString(string, hashTable):
    collisions = 0
    stop = False
    slot = (hashString(string, len(hashTable)))
    while not stop:
        if hashTable[slot] == None:
            hashTable[slot] = string
            stop = True
        else:
            slot = slot + (collisions**2)%len(hashTable)
            collisions = collisions + 1
        print('collisions: ', collisions)
```

My problem is that I keep getting IndexError: list index out of range and I am certain the problem lies in the else block however, I can't seem to find a solution for it. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: on what line is the exception happening?

Comment: Where are you getting the IndexError? The only indexing I see you doing is `hashTable[slot]`.

Comment: hashString is a function that takes strings as arguments and returns hashvalues. The error appears for the line with the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the inner-workings of your `hashString()` function, I assume you are taking a string and converting it into a hash of a given length. If that is true, your else statement sets a value that is out of bounds of your hashTable (again, just a guess since you don't give any inner workings of your hashTable).

The reason why this is happening is because you are actually making `slot` larger than the bounds when you:

`slot = slot + (collisions**2)%len(hashTable)`

By design, hashes are usually a given length, and you are just making it longer, thus out of bounds of your `hashTable`.

You need to mod the entire new slot to keep it from going out of bounds.

`slot = (slot + (collisions**2))%len(hashTable)`

Comment: Glad to help. If it worked, can you make the answer as correct? Thanks!